# add integers in nested XML child elements using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, quickbooks, iif

I receive an XML document with many child elements which I need to extract the info and then export to a CSV or text document so I can import to Quickbooks. The XML tree looks like the following:

```
<MODocuments>
  <MODocument>
    <Document>TX1126348</Document>
    <DocStatus>P</DocStatus>
    <DateIssued>20180510</DateIssued>
    <ApplicantName>COMPANY FRUIT &amp; VEGETABLE</ApplicantName>
    <MOLots>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>A</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>15500</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>B</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>175</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>C</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>7500</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>D</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>300</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
    </MOLots>
  </MODocument>
  <MODocument>
    <Document>TX1126349</Document>
    <DocStatus>P</DocStatus>
    <DateIssued>20180511</DateIssued>
    <ApplicantName>COMPANY FRUIT &amp; VEGETABLE</ApplicantName>
    <MOLots>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>A</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>25200</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>B</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>16800</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
    </MOLots>
  </MODocument>
  <MODocument>
    <Document>TX1126350</Document>
    <DateIssued>20180511</DateIssued>
    <ApplicantName>COMPANY FRUIT &amp; VEGETABLE</ApplicantName>
    <MOLots>
      <MOLot>
        <LotID>A</LotID>
        <ProductVariety>Yellow</ProductVariety>
        <TotalPounds>14100</TotalPounds>
      </MOLot>
    </MOLots>
  </MODocument>
</MODocuments>
```

I need to extract the TotalPounds from each MODocument parent so the output would look like this: 
DOCUMENT number, APPLICANT NAME, and TOTAL POUNDS added up for all the MOLots in that one document.

```
TX1126348   COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE 23475
TX1126349   COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE 42000
TX1126350   COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE 14100
```

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('TX_959_20180514131311.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

docCert = []
docComp = []
totalPounds=[]

for MODocuments in root:
    for MODocument in MODocuments:
        docCert.append(MODocument.find('Document').text)
        docComp.append(MODocument.find('ApplicantName').text)
        for MOLots in MODocument:
            for MOLot in MOLots:
                totalPounds.append(int(MOLot.find('TotalPounds').text))

for i in range(len(docCert)):
    print(i, docCert[i],' ', docComp[i], totalPounds[i])
```

This is my output, and I don't know how to add up the totals for each Document.. please help.

```
0 TX1126348   COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE 15500
1 TX1126349   COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE 175
2 TX1126350   COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE 7500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use lxml, you can have the XPath `sum()` function sum all of the TotalPounds for you.

Example...

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

tree = etree.parse("TX_959_20180514131311.xml")

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for mo_doc in tree.xpath("/MODocuments/MODocument"):
        csvwriter.writerow([mo_doc.xpath("Document")[0].text,
                            mo_doc.xpath("ApplicantName")[0].text,
                            int(mo_doc.xpath("sum(MOLots/MOLot/TotalPounds)"))])
```

contents of "output.csv"...

```
TX1126348,COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE,23475
TX1126349,COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE,42000
TX1126350,COMPANY FRUIT & VEGETABLE,14100
```

Also, you have lots of control over quoting, delimiters, etc. by writing the output with `csv`.

Comment: Looks like I need to install lxml. I have a Windows machine, so let me do some research and try this solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Simon - I also have a Windows machine and don't have any problems with lxml. I installed using pip. http://lxml.de/installation.html

Comment: I installed lxml and it ran, created the output.csv, but it's completely blank. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your XML file exactly like what you have in your question? If it's blank I don't think the xpaths are matching. Maybe add some print statements to debug. Like `print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))` to see what the tree looks like. Maybe also a `print("hit!")` in the `for` to see if you get 3 messages for each MODocument selected.

Comment: Ahh yes, I had one more parent level, I added it and now I get this error. I tried changing the `"` from `sum` into the `MOLots` portion but also get another error there. Should the double quotes be where they are at? `int(mod.xpath("sum(MOLots/MOLot/TotalPounds)"))])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @Simon - Sorry. I originally tested with python 2.7. When I run it with python 3.6 I'm able to reproduce the error. The error is caused by me  opening the csv as binary. I updated the `open()` in my code and tested with python 3.6 and it's working for me now. (Don't forget to update the xpath to account for your additional parent level.)

Comment: Works! Thank you very much for your help with this. I will do some more research on `lxml` so I can make a few more tweeks to the output. Any references you recommend? Again, Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Simon - You're welcome. Their website (http://lxml.de/) has a lot of good info. Anything I can't find on there I can find here on stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there will be more items in `totalPounds` than in `docCert` or `docComp`. I think you need to do something like this:

```
for MODocuments in root:
    for MODocument in MODocuments:
        docCert.append(MODocument.find('Document').text)
        docComp.append(MODocument.find('ApplicantName').text)
        sub_total = 0
        for MOLots in MODocument:
            for MOLot in MOLots:
                sub_total += int(MOLot.find('TotalPounds').text)
        totalPounds.append(sub_total)
```

Comment: This works exactly for adding the sub_total! Thank you very much! I like the other answer from Daniel Haley since it spits it out to a CSV, but I need to test it first.